# how to make clean if-else + return value

Tags: ruby, coding-style

When coding in Ruby, I frequently write something like this

```
  def someopp(param)
    r_val = nil
    begin
      r_val  = do_something(param)
    rescue Some::Error => e
      r_val  = {} 
    end
    r_val 
  end
```

I don't like the looks of it.  Declaring the return variable that doesn't really do anything, then a line again with just the var name in order to return it.  It's cumbersome.  I feel that, in Ruby, there must be way to make it more clean and pretty.  Any suggestion for syntactic sugar over here?

Answer (score 7):

```
def someopp(param)
  do_something(param)
rescue Some::Error
  {} 
end
```

or

```
def someopp(param)
  do_something(param) rescue {}
end
```

But not recomend to use inline-rescue!

Comment: It's worth noting that `rescue` can be at the same level as `def`, you don't necessarily need the `begin`. Also if you're not using `e`, don't capture it.

Comment: @Spikie : What are your objections against inline-rescue?

Comment: @user1934428  inline-rescue will be rescuing away StandardError and all its subclasses, like NameError -- meaning that even a typo in your code won't raise an error.Oppositely, ```begin``` and ```resuce```  block will bring your attention.

Comment: But I can also specify a class with inline rescue! I.e. `do_something(param) rescue Some::Error {}`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're really doing this exact thing very frequently (calling external dependencies that can raise exceptions and falling back to some default value), can generalize further:

```
def rescuing(*exceptions, with:)
  yield
rescue *exceptions
  with
end

value = rescuing(ZeroDivisionError, with: Float::INFINITY) { 3 / 0 }
# => Infinity
```

Though it would be better still if you could avoid the exceptions to begin with, if possible.